# Heroku bash: node: command not found

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, mongoose

Have someone out there got this error when starting a node app on heroku before?

```
2012-10-17T20:28:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2012-10-17T20:28:53+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: node: command not found
```

It seems like the Heroku app are missing node.

The app starts just fine locally. Both foreman start and node app.js.

```
{
    "name": "app-name",
    "description": "some desc",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "engines": {
        "node": "0.8.12",
        "npm":  "1.1.49"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express" : "2.5.9",
        "mongoose" : ">=2.6.0",
        "colibri" : "*",
        "jade": ">= 0.0.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the same error "bash: node: command not found" when I try "heroku run node"

Comment: Was there a solution to this?

Comment: If you're working with a branch other than master/main, prior to running your node commands, use `git push heroku dev:main` _(dev being the branch name)_

Answer (score 11):

What fixed it for me was to add the heroku/nodejs buildpack in heroku settings.

Comment: It "almost worked" for me. I have a hybrid app which in it's root directory, I have Ruby on Rails app, and inside Rails' `app` directory, I have my NodeJS app (a simple Vue JS). Heroku complained about not finding a some NodeJS directories which are not present in root dir obviously. Is there a way to tell Heroku where my NodeJS app is located?

Answer (score 8):

Old question, but, try adding an `engines` section to your `package.json`:

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.9.4",
    "npm": ">= 4.4.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

First, ensure that your application is using the heroku/nodejs buildpack:

```
$ heroku buildpacks
```

1. heroku/nodejs

If this is not the case then change your builpack to nodejs using :

```
$ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs
```

[Image of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TiSF.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshot of code or logs, copy it directly in your post.

Comment: thank you, this saved me tons of work. I use Python and Node in one repository and apparently it only registered Python

Answer (score 2):

> Heroku recognizes an app as Node.js by the existence of a package.json. Even if your app has no dependencies, you should still create a package.json that declares a name, version, and empty dependencies in order that it appear as a Node app.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs

Comment: I allready have a package.json. Edited my original question with it.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr:** Bumping into same issue, [`heroku restart`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ps#process-restarts) worked for me.

---

**Long version:** this is how it went:

1. In `heroku logs` I saw:

   ```
   heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished  
   heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`  
   app[web.1]: bash: node: command not found  
   heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127  
   heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path=/ host=node-network.herokuapp.com fwd=70.28.80.4 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
   heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to down
   ```
2. so I ran `heroku restart`, and got:

   ```
   heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
   heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
   app[web.1]: Listening on port 30693
   heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
   ```

Answer (score 2):

**What fixed mine was deleting package.json.lock.** I had my yarn.lock and package.json.lock.

Apparently, heroku does not like that.